# Insert Into temp table and Then Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use a temp table to insert data that will be later on updated.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    '' as LaterTobeUpdateField
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM OriginalTable
```

Then I update the temp table

```
UPDATE #MyTempTable
SET LaterTobeUpdateField = 'new text'
```

Since the original value of LaterTobeUpdateField was '', during the update I will get the following error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Is there a workaround other than declaring the temp table before is being used?

This also works, but its ugly

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    Address, 
    '             ' as LaterTobeUpdateField
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM OriginalTable
```

Comment: either the way you are doing it, creating the temp table first or defining the length of your column beforehand: `SELECT Name, Address, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'')  as LaterTobeUpdateField`

Comment: That works, post and I will select as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment: You could create the temp table first or defining the length of your column beforehand

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    Address, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'') as LaterTobeUpdateField
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM OriginalTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

A little wordy but safe solution:

```
declare @myTempTable(name varchar(50),
        address varchar(50),
        LaterTobeUpdateField varchar(20))
insert @myTempTable
select name, address, '' a from originalTable
--do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    '' as LaterTobeUpdateField
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM OriginalTable

ALTER TABLE #MyTempTable
ALTER COLUMN LaterTobeUpdateField NVARCHAR(20)

UPDATE #MyTempTable
SET LaterTobeUpdateField = 'new text'
```